Is it possible to generate documentation through an external file in Sphinx?
I'm working on a project using sphinx but I don't want to add the docstrings to the .py file. That's why I want to know if it's possible to generate documentation through an external file in Sphinx, referencing the main code, for example as Doxygen does with .dox files.
I did some research and the closest I got was to re-declare the function in a separate markdown. For example, if I have a foo(val:int) function in the python file I re-declare the function in the markdown for example using ```` and put the documentation there.
Markdown file:

````python

def foo(val:int):

'''...'''

````

What I would like is some way of referencing this function in a separate file, so as not to lose the autodoc features. What I'd like to know is if it's possible to use a directive like in doxygen to reference this code like @foo, @class

Did you try to use sphinx to generate raw XML from your .py files (with xml builder)? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html Then you can write your other documentation in other XML files. XSLT or other XML manipulation techniques can then be used to combine the two sources and generate complete HTML files out of them.
